# Replace Tab with variable spaces in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that needs to be read by an outside program that uses spaces to delineate between rows.

As of right now the program reads:
Field 1 then 6 spaces, field 2 then 2 spaces, field 3 1 space, field 4 2 spaces and so on.
[image]
When I modified the doc in excel, it is now tab delineated between each field.
[image]
How would I write a python script to be able to replace this white space with the proper number of so that this program can read my file?

Comment: As an aside, you’ve tagged Python 2.7.  As you might be aware, 2.7 has been out of support since Jan 2020, with the latest release being 3.10.  Might be (definitely is) worth an upgrade, if your system allows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"{:10s}{:3s}{:4s}".format(*fields)` to do this. You just have to know the field widths.

Comment: I am super new to python, but I am guessing that the :10s is going to add spaces to whatever field it is?

Comment: The `{:10s}` says "print this value in a field 10 spaces wide".  In your case, "adding two spaces" is NOT the right answer.  Your third column has "HY3" and "CY" and "DY"; those need varying amounts of padding.